# What does "To-may-to, to-mah-to" mean?

Tags: expressions

What does "to-may-to, to-mah-to" mean?

I've seen this expression a few times and it seems to indicate some sort of equality. But what does it really mean?

Comment: @WillHunting it's what Brett answered :)

Comment: it's instructive to hear the song [Ella F. and Louis Armstrong - Let's Call the Whole Thing Off](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J2oEmPP5dTM)

Comment: Theta30's comment should be expanded into an answer. That is, in fact, the origin of the expression.

Comment: Go for it @Theta30

Comment: Related: [Is “po-TAH-to” an acceptable pronunciation for “potato”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/53019/is-po-tah-to-an-acceptable-pronunciation-for-potato)

Comment: @Theta30 I've always liked the Noel Coward take on it (You say pot-AY-to and I say pot-AY-to, you say tom-AH-to and I say tom-AH-to, I can't see what the problem is myself).

Answer (score 32):

It refers to the George Gershwin song, "Let's Call The Whole Thing Off", which is a duet between two characters from different social classes, and therefore different accents.

> You say eether and I say eyether,
>
> You say neether and I say nyther,
>
> Eether, eyether, neether, nyther,
>
> Let's call the whole thing off!
>
> You like potayto and I like potahto,
>
> You like tomayto and I like tomahto,
>
> Potayto, potahto, tomayto, tomahto!
>
> Let's call the whole thing off!

Nowadays, it's often used when someone feels that the same thing is being referred to using different words.

> "I think David Beckham is past his best"
>
> "Well, he's not as young as he was"
>
> "Oh, tomayto, tomahto"

Comment: It's interesting that in the "original" (the song lyrics), that difference in pronunciation (among many others) is actually portrayed as being so significant that it's enough reason to end the romance! But in the modern usage, it's just a way of saying that your apparent difference in opinion is either trivial or doesn't really exist at all (being just a matter of the same thing being said different ways).

Comment: @FumbleFingers It's not that the pronunciation is a reason to end a romance, it's simply emblematic of all the various differences between the two characters.  If anything, given the whole song, it's not a good enough reason at all.  It's more like the same level of severity as if they got into an argument over how to hang the guest towels in the bathroom.

Comment: @Phoenix: Sure, it's "emblematic" - but that's an implied *interpretation*. Sticking to the actual words of the song, it gives *nine* examples of pronunciation differences (plus one word-order). No other reasons for ending the relationship are explicitly stated. Anyway, my point was simply that pronunciation differences in that song are a metaphor for **relational disharmony**, whereas in the modern usage they're a metaphoric way of brushing aside trivial differences.

Comment: I've always wondered if this expression might have gained strength with the marriage of Franklin Delano Roosevelt and his distant cousin Eleanor Roosevelt.  Reportedly the two pronounced "Roosevelt" differently.

Answer (score 8):

It refers to different ways of saying *tomato*. It means it doesn't matter whether you say it with a different accent, it's still the same thing. So the expression means: it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 5):

It's a way of dismissing a noted or claimed or supposed difference between two things as trivial.

Attitudinally, it combines an acknowledgement of some difference while simultaneously waving that difference away as not worth bothering with.

And because the pronunciation "to-mah-to" is, at least to ears attuned to US pronunciation, connotatively "upper class," the dismissal gains a subtle heft since to insist on the validity of the "*obviously*" a trivial difference makes one fussy and highfalutin, a stickler and a snob over petty differences. And that's always a no-no.

There's a class game neatly embedded into the expression, which is there even without benefit of the lyrics from which the phrase was spun-out -- testimony to the verbal genius of Ira Gershwin (though I might have guessed it was Cole Porter, who was also capable of such a feat.)

@Theta Thanks for that great link!

Comment: +1 for pointing out the "class game" aspect! I always wondered as a child why two differences in pronunciation was enough reason to break off a romance.

Answer (score 3):

TO-MAY-TO, TO-MAH-TO. Meaning, It's really the same thing. It doesn't matter how you say it or if you use synonyms. Its still the same thing/meanin/word.

Comment: Welcome to [ELU.SE] @ghost. We are looking for definitive answers to definitive questions, where the best answer can be voted up. Please see the [help]. This answer seems to restate what others have said without adding new.

Answer (score 2):

Some corrections about the song (though that is tomato/tomahto re: this discussion)

1. Ira Gershwin wrote the lyrics. George the music.
2. Other lyrics are:

> But oh! If we call the whole thing off,
>   Then we must part.
>   And oh! If we ever part, 
>   Then that might break my heart!

The last line is:

> For we know we need each other so we
>   Better call the calling off off,
>   Let's call the whole thing off.

They want to stay together, so they call off the calling off. Meaning, these reasons are trivial compared to what we mean to each other.

Comment: Is this an answer, or did you want to comment on one of the answers? (if that was the case, I can ask a moderator to make this into a comment, even if you don't have enough reputation for them yet)

Comment: Psst...! explain what "to-may-to and to-mah-to" means nowadays and your answer (which I like) won't risk deletion.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it addresses different options.
It's about people refusing to agree on something. So the solution is to call things off

Comment: Except in the song they *don't* call things off in the end, and never really wanted to.