# Pronunciation of "automata"

Tags: pronunciation, pronunciation-vs-spelling

Automata theory is a study in the fields of theoretical computer science and mathematics. [See this Wikipedia page for more information.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automata_theory) What is the pronunciation of the word *automata*?  Is it *auto-m-A-ta* (where the capital *A* says its name) or *auto-m-ah-ta*?

Comment: It's an American accent, but [this MW page](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/automata) has a button you can click on to hear pronunciation of this plural of *automaton*. Not that in *my UK* accent it's "ORtomata", not "Atomata".

Comment: Thanks, that answers my question.  Just out of curiosity, why the down vote?  Did I break some rule?  I'd like to know so I don't repeat it again.

Comment: It doesn't mean you committed a cardinal sin. Perhaps I was a bit harsh. I happen to know MW has pronunciations, and when I went to look I half-expected to find that they didn't pronounce the plural, which would explaqin why you asked here. When I found they *did* I was just a bit tetchy, thinking "Well, he could have found that himself!". Okay - on reflection that was definitely a bit ott, so I'll reverse it.

Comment: I see. That makes sense.  I did check one online dictionary, but it didn't contain the plural.  In retrospect, I should have searched more before posting on this site.  I understand the down vote now.  Thanks!

Comment: ho hum. I just reversed, but apparently someone else downvoted anyway. Maybe it's one of those ["to-may-to, to-mah-to"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/55062/what-does-to-may-to-to-mah-to-mean) things.

Comment: @FumbleFingers You really can’t use MW for pronunciations, you know. It doesn’t use IPA.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Did you really mean **Not that in my UK accent it's "ORtomata", not "Atomata".**? Am I just imagining a missing ***e*** after Not?

Comment: @Kris: Ooops. Must have been a bad day. NOTE THAT IT'S NOTE NOT NOT in my first comment!

Comment: Now this beats me! "NOTE THAT IT'S NOTE NOT NOT" lol -- Oh yes, exactly, I agree.

Comment: @tchrist: I'm not big on looking up pronunciation myself - there are variations, particularly regional (not least of which are US/UK differences). Mostly I repeat what I hear others say - if I can't do that I just guess from the orthography and take note if anyone corrects me. But by and large if I don't hear others use a word, I don't use it myself anyway. Language is for communication, not for proving to other people that you know words they don't. (Except here on ELU, of course! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's *au-TOM-ah-tah*, the plural of automaton (*au-TOM-ah-ton* - proper pronunciation [here](http://www.google.co.uk/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=define%3a%20automaton)) but not to be confused with automation (*au-to-MAY-tion*).

I have no idea why the difference exists. However, I note that it's similar to the difference in better known words 
 robot (*RO-bot*) and robotics (*ro-BOT-ics*).

Hopefully someone who has more familiarity with formal pronunciation notation and / or etymology can help fill in the gaps.

Comment: Your wish is granted; or rather, both wishes. ☺

Answer (score 5):

The [*OED’s entry*](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/13474) gives the pronunciation of *automaton* as:

> Brit.  /ɔːˈtɒmət(ə)n/, U.S.  /ɔˈtɑməd(ə)n/,  /ɑˈtɑməd(ə)n/,  /ɔːˈtɑməˌtɑn/,  /ɑˈtɑməˌtɑn/.

Looks like there’s plenty to choose from there! ☺  My own is **/ɔːˈtɒməˌtɑn/** in the singular, and of course **/-ə/** in the plural. (I don’t have the cot–caught merger.)

The notes under the etymology are particulary copious:

> **Etymology**:  < classical Latin *automatum*  automatic contrivance and its etymon ancient Greek *αὐτόματον*  marionette, use as noun of neuter of *αὐτόματος*  (adjective) acting of itself, spontaneous, (of plants) growing by themselves, (of events) happening by themselves < *αὐτό‑* [**auto‑** *comb. form*¹](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/13367)  + *‑ματος*  < the same Indo‐European base as Sanskrit *mata*  thought, considered, classical Latin *‑mentus*  (in *commentus*  feigned), Lithuanian *mintas*  trodden, stamped, representing a participial formation < the Indo‐European base of ancient Greek *μέμονα*  (see [**i‑mind** *n*.](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/251873). Compare [**automa** *n*.](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/13452), [**automate** *n*.](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/13459), [**autom** *n*.](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/13477)
>
> Compare the following slightly earlier attestation of ancient Greek *αὐτόματον*  in an English context:
>
> - 1611        T. Coryate *Crudities* sig. T8ᵛ,          The picture of a Gentlewoman, whose eies were contriued‥, that they moued vp and down of themselues,‥done by a vice which the Grecians call αὐτόματον.
>
> The Greek noun was also borrowed into other European languages, in some of these indirectly (via Latin or another language). Compare e.g. French *automate* [**automate** n.](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/13459), Spanish *autómato*  (1582), (now usually) *autómata*  (1729), Portuguese *autômato*  (1712), Italian *automa*, †*automato*  (see [**automa** n.](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/13452)), Dutch *automaat*  (1813; earlier with Greek or Latin endings: †*automata*, plural (1552), †*automaton*  (1558), †*automatum*  (1769)), German *Automat* [**automat** n](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/13455).
>
> In plural form *automata*  after the Greek and Latin plural forms. The plural forms *automata*  and *automatons*  coexist in modern English. Attempts to establish semantic guidelines for the use of the two plural forms are rare in modern usage guides; apparently the only such attempt is made in R. W. Burchfield *New Fowler’s Mod. Eng. Usage* (ed. 3, 1998) 79/2, which states (echoing earlier statements in various editions of H.W. Fowler *Mod. Eng. Usage*): ‘The plural is *automata*  when used collectively, otherwise (much less commonly) *automatons*’. Several usage guides merely comment that the *‑s*  plural is more common, or that the plural form *automata*  belongs to the learned register. Corpus evidence suggests that the *‑s*  plural is especially frequent in the transferred sense  3c.
>
> **CITATION**
>
> automaton, n.
>
> Third edition, June 2011; online version December 2011. http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/13474; accessed 19 January 2012. An entry for this word was first included in *New English Dictionary*, 1885.

The *OED*’s ‘transferred sense 3c’ referenced above is the one about somebody acting like a machine, and corresponds to the *RAE*’s sense 3.  The *OED* also admits a sense 4 from the field of Computing.

For the record, the [*RAE* entry for *autómata*](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=aut%F3mata) confirms that the current Spanish spelling, *autómata*, is not just masculine (just like all the other -*ata* words of Greek derivation in Spanish), but also **singular**. So Spanish *este autómata* is singular where English *these automata* is plural, as all students of finite automata know. The Spanish plural would be *estos autómatas*, oddly enough, which risks sounding like a double-plural to the English ear. English *finite automata* translates to *los autómatas finitos* in Spanish.

Comment: What would be the 'English' singular *automaton* in Spanish then?

Comment: @Kris English singular *automaton* = Spanish singular *autómata*; English plural *automata* = Spanish plural *autómatas*