# You say potato, i say

Tags: pronunciation

Does anyone pronounce potato that way, rhyming with British tomato?

I've heard of the song before and wondered about potato as it mentioned tomato pronounced both ways, but I've only just listened to it (it's called Let's Call the Whole Thing off) and was surprised that it does say potato that way...

Comment: Do you mean /pəˈtɑːtəʊ/?

Comment: @Laurel Yes, I do.

Comment: Actually, I just realised that my question is a duplicate of https://english.stackexchange.com/q/53019/173856. Sorry.